# C: Program that recursively computes matrix determinant

Tags: c

I am trying to make this program, but it is not working, its failing in attributing values for the second line of the aux matrix, and i cant see why, can anyone help me? Thanks!

Oh, and I have already putted some debugging lines, and, apparently, everything is fine, it's just not attributing the values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void zerar(int n,int m[][n]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
            m[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

void printm(int n, int matriz[][n]) {
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
            printf("\t%d", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int det(int n, int m[][n]) {
    int i, j, k, x, y, soma=0, aux[n][n];
    zerar(n, aux);
    if (n < 1) {}
    else if (n == 1) {
        return m[0][0];
    }
    else if (n == 2) {
        soma = (m[0][0] * m[1][1]) - (m[0][1] * m[1][0]);
        return soma;
    }
    else {
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
            for (j=1, x=0; j<n; j++) {
                for (k=0, y=0; k<n; k++) {
                    if (k == i) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        printf("\n\n");
                        printf("\nx=%d, y=%d, j=%d, k=%d, i=%d\n", x, y, j, k, i);
                        aux[x][y] = m[j][k];
                        printm(n-1, aux);
                        y++;
                    }
                }
                x++;
            }
            soma += m[0][i]*pow(-1, i+2)*det(n-1, aux);
        }
        return soma;
    }
}


int main()
{
    int m[3][3] = {{4, 3, 2}, {1, 4, 5}, {2, 1, 2}};
    det(3, m);
    printf("%d", det(3, m));
    printf("\n\n");
    printm(3, m);
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: `aux[10][10]` --> `aux[n][n]`

Comment: It's a improvement, thanks! But don't solve the problem :(

Comment: It worked for me by changing `aux` to `aux[n-1][n-1]`.

Comment: Thanks very much! You are genius! Can someone explain me please why it have to be that way? I'm not understanding.

Comment: This doesn't affect the behavior, but note that `pow(-1, i+2)` is just `pow(-1, i)`

Comment: I know, thanks, haha. It was just one of the many attempts to make the program work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the input matrix is of size `n x n`, the size of the auxiliary matrix, `aux`, needs to be `n-1 x n-1`.

Change

```
int i, j, k, x, y, soma=0, aux[n][n];
```

to

```
int i, j, k, x, y, soma=0, aux[n-1][n-1];
```

You said in a comment:

> Can someone explain me please why it have to be that way?

If you use `aux[n][n]` and `n` is 3, the memory layout of the object is:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

and you fill up the data as though it is a `2 x 2` matrix.

```
0           1           2
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| x | x |   | x | x |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

In the next recursive call, you treat that memory as though it is a `2 x 2` array.

```
0       1              
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| x | x |   | x | x |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
         ^        ^
         |        Ignored
         Using uninitialized array element
```

In theory, the program is subject to undefined behavior if you use `aux[n][n]` instead of `aux[n-1][n-1]`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain me why it wasn't working and with this it works? I'm not understanding.

Comment: For a 2-dimensional array, the index for `m[i][j]` is computed as `i * width + j`.  That converts a 2-dimensional index into the 1-dimensional index that's used internally.  If the width is incorrect, then it will access the wrong element.

Comment: Thanks guys! You helped me a lot in comprehending this!